# Merge two tables of SIMILAR structure

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that have virtually identical content and very similar structure. They were our live database vs our dev database. Our dev database schema has been changed a little to reflect needs but now we need it to become the new live structure.. So I just need delete the data out of our dev table and import what's currently live into the dev using the new dev structure.

Our table structure is massive or I'd post the differences but I'd think the concept is general.

if anyone has any advice that'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Question seems too broad, but the general approach would be `INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table`, but you might have to modify the column list in the `SELECT` part if your data needs modifications due to the differences in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise to `ALTER TABLE` live table, if that is not appropriate use

```
INSERT INTO `dev` (`field1`, `field2` ..., `fieldN`) 
SELECT `field1live`, `field2live` ..., `fieldNlive` FROM `live`
```

fieldXlive can be replaced with migration expression for his column.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
INsert into table .... on duplicate key update
```